# Obtener máximos o mínimos de una lista de valores en java

Tags: java

Cómo se pueden obtener dos o más valores máximos o mínimos de una lista de enteros en java? Sé obtener el máximo y el mínimo, pero los dos valores más grandes no, cómo se haría? Gracias.

Comment: Has pensado en que, una vez obtenido el valor lo elimines del listado y vuelves a obtener el mayor?

Comment: Ordenando la lista y cogiendo los dos primeros o los dos últimos

Comment: Hay varias formas de hacer esto. Y si usas Java 8+ puedes recurrir a las expresiones Lambda. Convendría que investigues, que intentes un código y que plantées la pregunta en base a lo que hayas intentado.

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas, pero habría alguna forma de obtener los dos mayores valores de una lista de enteros sin modificar el orden de dicha lista ni eliminar elementos?

Answer (score 1):

Aqui tienes un ejemplo de como ordenar un List y ya luego sacas el índice que necesites. Recuerda importar `Collections`

```
public class Principal {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<>();

    numeros.add(3);
    numeros.add(1);
    numeros.add(6);
    numeros.add(4);
    numeros.add(10);

    System.out.println("Antes de ordenar: ");
    for(Integer num: numeros){
        System.out.println(num);
    }

    Collections.sort(numeros);
    //Collections.reverse(numeros); <-- para ordenar descendiente

    System.out.println("Despues de ordenar: ");
    for(Integer num: numeros){
        System.out.println(num);
    }

    //Recuperas el índice que necesites
    int index = numeros.size() - 2;

    System.out.println("Penúltimo valor mas alto: " + numeros.get(index));
    System.out.println("Valor mas alto: " + numeros.get(index + 1));
}
}
```

Espero te sirva, un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas, pero habría alguna forma de obtener los dos mayores valores de una lista de enteros sin modificar el orden de dicha lista ni eliminar elementos?

Comment: Si solamente necesitas recoger esos numeros, te recomendaria hacer una copia del List creando uno temporal, ordenas este segundo y solo conservas el primero. Ejemplo: `List<Integer> numerosTemp = new ArrayList<Integer>(numeros);`

Answer (score -1):

Basado en el código de [@Tadius](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/64175/tadius), pero iterando y guardando el máximo y el casi máximo (y un tempmax para hacer el swap)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Integer max = 0;
    Integer casimax = 0;
    Integer tempmax = 0;
    List<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<>();

    numeros.add(3);
    numeros.add(1);
    numeros.add(6);
    numeros.add(16);
    numeros.add(4);
    numeros.add(10);

    System.out.println("num \t casi \t max");

    for(Integer num: numeros){
      if ( num > casimax ) {
        casimax = num;
      }
      if ( casimax > max ) {
        tempmax = max;
        max = casimax;
        casimax = tempmax;
      }

      System.out.println( num + " \t "+ casimax + " \t " + max );
    }

    System.out.println("Penúltimo valor mas alto: " + casimax);
    System.out.println("Valor mas alto: " + max);
    }
}
```